# is there any sample shell script to load data from AWS S3 to MySQL RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Please provide if you guys have some idea/any sample shell script to load data from AWS S3 to MySQL (RDS) instance.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Like where are you failing? Have you tried to write that script yet?

Comment: Check: [Restoring a Backup into an Amazon RDS MySQL DB Instance :: Importing Data From Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.PerformingImport).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 steps.

Step 1 - Download the CSV file.

```
wget <s3-csv-url>
```

Step 2 - Use the [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to import the data from csv to your MySQL database.

In case you are using an Aurora Instance, you could simply use the [LOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html) command to import data from S3 to your database table.